# Why isn't Freetype loading a font in my .exe

Tags: c++, opengl, freetype

I have written an application that uses FreeType to render text onto a window. I have built the debug and release version which both run fine from visual studio 2015. I have set my runtime library for linking to /MDd. I also included the font OCRAEXT.TTF in resource files.

Here is the code the uses FreeType:

```
TextRenderer::TextRenderer(GLuint width, GLuint height)
{
    //Load and configure shader
    this->TextShader = ResourceManager::LoadShader("VertexText.vert", "FragmentText.frag", nullptr, "text");
    this->TextShader.SetMatrix4("projection", glm::ortho(0.0f, static_cast<GLfloat>(width), static_cast<GLfloat>(height), 0.0f), GL_TRUE);
    this->TextShader.SetInteger("text", 0);

    //configure VAO/VBO for texture quads
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &this->VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &this->VBO);
    glBindVertexArray(this->VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * 6 * 4, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}


void TextRenderer::Load(std::string font, GLuint fontSize)
{
    //first clear the previously loaded characters
    this->Characters.clear();

    //then initialise and load the Freetype library
    FT_Library ft;
    if (FT_Init_FreeType(&ft))  //All functions return a value different than 0 whenever an error occurred
        std::cout << "ERROR::FREETYPE: Could not init freetype library" << std::endl;

    //Load font as face
    FT_Face face;
    if (FT_New_Face(ft, font.c_str(), 0, &face))
        std::cout << "ERROR::FREETYPE: Failed to load font" << std::endl;

    //set size to load glyphs as
    FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, fontSize);

    //disable byte-alignment restriction
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    //then for the first 128 ASCII characters, pre-load/compile their characters and store them
    for (GLubyte c = 0; c < 128; c++)
    {
        //Load character glyph
        if (FT_Load_Char(face, c, FT_LOAD_RENDER))
        {
            std::cout << "ERROR::FREETYPE: Failed to load glyph" << std::endl;
            continue;
        }

        //generate texture
        GLuint texture;
        glGenTextures(1, &texture);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        glTexImage2D(
            GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            0,
            GL_RED,
            face->glyph->bitmap.width,
            face->glyph->bitmap.rows,
            0,
            GL_RED,
            GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
            face->glyph->bitmap.buffer
            );

        //set texture options
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        //Now store character for later use
        Character character =
        {
            texture,
            glm::ivec2(face->glyph->bitmap.width, face->glyph->bitmap.rows),
            glm::ivec2(face->glyph->bitmap_left, face->glyph->bitmap_top),
            face->glyph->advance.x,
        };
        Characters.insert(std::pair<GLchar, Character>(c, character));

    }
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    //destroy FreeType once we're finished
    FT_Done_Face(face);
    FT_Done_FreeType(ft);
}
```

In my Game class I have an initialise function that contains these lines of code:

```
Text = new TextRenderer(this->Width, this->Height);
    Text->Load("fonts/OCRAEXT.TTF", 24);
```

The problem is that when I try to run the standalone .exe, I get the message "ERROR::FREETYPE: Failed to load font" and the .exe. stops running. I've tried to debug this and I get a message that says "unhandled exception at 0x00730072 in Game.exe. 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00730072."

The breakpoint points to this line of code:

```
FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, fontSize);
```

I've tried stepping through the code to figure out the problem, but little made sense. Could someone please explain what could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

`FT_New_Face` expects a path in the file system. PE resources are not located in the filesystem, hence trying to locate the file fails and you get this error.

You have to use `FT_New_Memory_Face` instead; the memory location of the resource can be retrieved using the [Resource API (link to MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648008%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Instead of using `LoadLibrary` use `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` to retrieve a handle to the PE image of the process.